# Am getting the error "Unknown template object: function" in my ember 1.9.1 app?

Tags: ember.js

I've upgraded my ember version to 1.9.1 and handlebar version to 2.0.0. But now getting the error "Unknown template object: function" in app. The app worked perfectly with ember 1.8.1 and handlebars 1.3.0.

Comment: Did you upgrade your template pre-compiler when you upgraded Handlebars?

Comment: Yeah I've updated ember-template-compiler. One ember-template-compiler.js file is available in ./bower_components/ember/ and it's COMPILER_REVISION is 6. Also I've replaced ember-template-compiler folder in ./My_App/node_modules/ with the one ember-template-compiler for version 1.9.

Comment: I should have asked this before, but how are you compiling your templates?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me very much. There's several Grunt plugins to compile templates. Can you tell me which plugin you're using? Is it possibly [this one](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates)?

Comment: Hey sorry, yeah. Am using grunt-ember-templates version 0.5.0. TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I now realize that you mentioned that in your other comment. That helps. Just one more thing, can you post your Grunt configuration for `grunt-ember-templates`?

Comment: You mean the file Gruntfile.js inside grunt-ember-templates folder?

Comment: No, wherever you put your custom options for the template compiler (like the path to your templates and the output file). More likely than not you have an `initConfig()` call in your Gruntfile that has a object with an `emberTemplates` property in it. I want those options.

Comment: You can find the configuration for grunt-ember-templates in http://ideone.com/Yt0V25

Comment: @GJK Thanks for your time, now my templates compiled successfully, but getting one error, "Cannot read property 'template' of undefined". Can you help me with fixing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, you're not using the correct template compiler for your version of Ember. The [grunt-ember-templates readme](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates#using-ember-v110) has instructions on this, but the gist is that you need to point it to the correct template compiler like this:

```
options: {
    templateCompilerPath: 'bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js',
    handlebarsPath: 'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js',
    templateNamespace: 'HTMLBars'
}
```

You can also look at [this pull request](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates/pull/77) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. Fixed the issue. And now it's perfectly running. :)